# How to implement boundary conditions for the Thomas algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, pde, finite-difference, matrix, implicit-methods

For my variable $U(t,x)$, I have implemented the thomas algorithm with $U_j^i$:

$$ a(x)U_{j-1}^{i+1}+ b(x)U_j^{i+1} + c(x)U_{j+1}^{i+1} = d(x)U_j^{i} $$

Then $\textbf{A}$ is a tridiagonal vector with coefficients $a,b,c$ and I solve using $Au=d$. I can get this working fine. The issue is that I want to implement the boundary conditions:

$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} = 0, \quad x\rightarrow \infty$$
$$  b(0)U_0^{i+1}+ c(0)U_{1}^{i+1} = d(0)U_0^{i} , \quad x=0$$

For the **second** boundary condition, if we let:
$$
A=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
b & 0 \\
0 & c \\
\end{array}\right]
,
u=
\left[\begin{array}{c}
U_0^{i+1} \\
U_1^{i+1} \\
\end{array}\right]
,
d=
\left[\begin{array}{c}
d(0)U_0^{i} \\
\end{array}\right]
$$

Then obviously the RHS is a 1x1 matrix which doesn’t work as we require the RHS to be a 2x1.

I am aware that there is an algorithm using positions $0,1,2$, but I want to use only $0,1$ for the boundary. How do I solve that condition?

For the 1st condition, (the Neumann condition), if:

$$-U_t + \alpha(x)U + \beta(x)U_x + \gamma(x)U_{xx} = 0$$

Then my pde becomes $$U_t = \alpha(x)U$$ at my very large $x$?

So that would be:

$$\frac{U_{j_{max}}^{i+1} -  U_{j_{max}}^{i}}{dt} = \alpha(j_{max})U_{j_{max}}^{i+1}$$

$$U_{j_{max}}^{i+1} = \frac{1}{ \alpha(j_{max}) dt} U_{j_{max}}^{i}$$

Is this correct?

If you want complete context, I am trying to solve equation (4,20) with boundary conditions (4.22) and (4.23) [from this paper](https://pure.manchester.ac.uk/ws/portalfiles/portal/208486475/FULL_TEXT.PDF)

Comment: Is the correlation with the Thomas algorithm here really necessary? Put differently, do you know how to include the boundary conditions directly into the linear system?

Comment: I am unsure how you are dealing with the condition as $x\to\infty$. Are you just fixing a finite grid and enforcing $U_x=0$ at the rightmost grid point?

Comment: @whpowell96 yes, I'm just making $U_x = 0$ at the last point, which also means $U_{xx} = 0$. Therefore we only have the time derivative.

Comment: @davidhigh I was only using the Thomas algorithm as that was what the author used. But it makes sense too because it's a tridiagonal system

Comment: $U_x(x_n)=0\not\implies U_{xx}(x_n)=0$

Comment: @THAT'SMYQUANTMYQUANTITATIV: I mentioned that because these are two different levels of the whole approach: First, I would formulate the problem -- I guess it comes from a differential equation -- with all required boundary conditions. Only thereafter, I would pick a suitable solution method (and maybe use the Thomas algorithm if the problem matrix was still tridiagonal). In your question, you tackle the boundary conditions only after you applied the solution method.